# Toggling button text not working

Tags: jquery

Ok, I want to toggle the text in the button when I click a button:

```
$('.text-btn').click(function () {
  $('.text-btn').toggle();
});
```

and it works fine in the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/labanino/VLc2F/2/)** but when I add it to my .js file it does not work. I guess maybe it's conflicting with my .js, I don't know. If you get rid of all .js leaving on ly the toggle code at the end of it you can see it works fine. Any help please? **[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/labanino/VLc2F/2/)**.Thanks.

Comment: can you add the rest of your html to your fiddle ?

Comment: Is jQuery UI needed for .modal or just "main" 2.0.2?

Comment: @MichaelGeary, thanks. Because the fiddle is not loading UI. Labanino, are you including UI also? What other .js are you including?

Comment: I would say there is nothing wrong with your toggle part, in your fiddle you have some datepicker and boostrap errors. Did you load those .js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always check your console for error, in your fiddle the plugin date time picker for bootstrap is missing, so you can try include this: `http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js` in your code.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hieuh25/VLc2F/3/

**EDIT:**

The issue now is toggle functionality doesn't work on popover: http://jsfiddle.net/labanino/whcya/1/

Because the popover is dynamically added by JS, you should bind click handler on popover's callback. Since Bootstrap popover doesn't provide a callback handler officially, we need to extend it a bit:

```
var tmp = $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.show;
$.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.show = function () {
    tmp.call(this);
    if (this.options.callback) {
        this.options.callback();
    }
}

$('[rel=popover]').popover({
    html: true,
    content: function () {
        return $(this).siblings('.popover').html();
    },
    callback: function () {
        $('.text-btn').click(function () {
            /*alert('What's going on!');*/
            $('.text-btn').toggle();
        });
    }
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hieuh25/whcya/3/

Hope this helps.

Comment: The thing is that I use a datepicker in other pages no in that one, what should I do then, put the datepicker reference even though I'm not using it on this page? Thanks.

Comment: You should include the JS library when your code needs it. If you execute the whole JS file you gave us in the fiddle then yes you should include datetime picker library then. Anyhow, always check your console for error ;)

Comment: I just found out about it and still don't have an answer to this issue but for some reason can't trigger any event in a popover in boostrap, even an alert(); Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/labanino/whcya/1/

Comment: Please check my edited answer above.